# How to detect when user navigates to new screen in flutter inappwebview

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, i just started using this package flutter_inappwebview to display a google form in my flutter application, i want to be able to detect in my flutter application when user successfully submits a response to the Google form. That is when user moves from: 
[image] 
 to this one: 
[image]. 
 I tried using the onLoadStart but it was not of help. your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

It has a callback to detect the current URL of the webview.Please follow the below snippet of the code in your project:

```
Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
          // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          ].toSet(),
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            //here request will provide you various information about the current page with the URL you want to know about
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
    );
```

Comment: The question is regarding a specific package